# Quelle serait une autre façon d’écrire: « Il est passé de culturiste à obèse. »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique

Je cherche une façon plus jolie de donner corps à cette  idée.

Merci.

Comment: Le muscle s'est transformé en gras.

Comment: Vu que l'obésité se mesure officiellement grâce à l'IMC, beaucoup de culturistes sont en fait techniquement déjà obèses... je comprends que ca n'est pas l'idée de la question mais du coup je pense que les réponses faisant référence à la graisse ou la corpulence sont à privilégier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Il faisait du culturisme mais il arrêté et il est devenu obèse. (*factuel*)
- Il a perdu sa silhouette d'athlète pour se retrouver avec celle d'un obèse. (*factuel*)
- Sa silhouette, de  celle d'un culturiste par force d'exercice s'est transformée par laisser aller  en celle d'un obèse. (*factuel, explicatif*)
- D'un enthousiasme  pour le culturisme il s'est retranché dans une confortable obésité. (*tendancieux*)
- D'un idéal supposément dédié au culturisme il s'est apparemment résigné à l'obésité. (*sceptique*)
- Il faisait du culturisme, maintenant il fait de l'obésité. (*un certain cynisme*)
- Il ne voyait que par culturisme, maintenant il est obèse. (*pointe de cynisme*)
- Il ne jurait que par culturisme pour en arriver finalement à devenir obèse. (*pointe de cynisme*)
- Il y a ceux dont on résume l'existence par l'expression « des chiffons aux richesses », chez lui il doit falloir changer les mots en « Monsieur muscle » et « l'obésité », il exulte. (*cas particulier*)

Comment: Je dois dire qu'à part les 2 premières, ces propositions semblent très ampoulées ou pompeuses, et absolument pas naturelles... mais c'est un question de goût et cela répond d'une certaine manière à la question qui demande une formule "plus jolie"

Comment: La dernière proposition m'a laissé très perplexe jusqu'à ce que je comprenne qu'elle était calquée de l'anglais *from rags to riches* mais elle reste malgré cela assez tirée par les cheveux et je ne comprends pas pourquoi la personne exulte.

Comment: @LaurentS. Je n'arrive pas à partager votre point de vue ; dire par exemple que la troisième phrase n'aurait peut-être pas un effet naturel dans la bouche de tout le monde vu le côté indubitablement littéraire qu'on peut lui reconnaitre, est une chose concevable, mais la bannir carrément des formes de l'expression est une toute autre chose. On ne peut pas refuser à l'être littéraire de se confiner au familier dans sa conversation, et on ne le veut pas, qu'il parle comme il écrit ! (1/2)

Comment: @LaurentS.Évidemment, ceci est une opinion à ne pas prendre comme un absolu, mais elle répond  au fait que ce serait une erreur de réprimer l'élan artistique ; la littérature n'est pas un embellissement de la pensée humaine, elle est sa plus haute expression. (2/2)

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, j'admet que ce n'est pas facile et personnellement, si quelque chose de cette sorte m'était dit je pourrais avoir à tendre l'oreille et répliquer par un « Il exulte ? ». Il se réjouit tout simplement de sa nouvelle liberté de manger à sa faim et ne souffre nullement de son obésité, comme le nouveau riche qui profite de la vie allègrement.

Comment: Je ne la bannis pas, j'ai d'ailleurs donné un vote à votre réponse, je tenais juste à préciser pour l'OP qu'on est ici plus souvent dans la formulation littéraire que dans celle de tous les jours (pour la plupart des personnes en tout cas)

Comment: @LPH Qu'est-ce que tu entends par "littéraire" ?

Comment: @jlliagre Dans ce cas de phrase, la troisième, ce qui est littéraire, selon ma compréhension, ça serait le langage et l'insistence sur une idée d'opposition ; d'abord, l'apposition n'est pas une tournure usuelle de la langue parlée ;  ensuite, les parallèles ne sont pas nécessairement soulignés par des tournures explicites et concises (par … par …). En langage moins sophistiqué on aurait pu dire « Il avait une silhouette de culturiste mais pas de naissance, il faisait de l'exercice, et elle s'est transformée en celle d'un obèse parce qu'il a arrêté de prendre soin de son apparence. ».

Comment: Est-ce que tu considères la préposition inattendue (***par** force de* au lieu de ***à** force de*) comme littéraire aussi ?

Comment: @jlliagre Il y a peut-être dans cette troisième phrase un problème pour la tournure « par force d'exercice » ; je ne trouve pas de précédent, mais ce que j'entends n'est pas « **à** force d'exercice ».

Comment: @jlliagre Cependant, on trouve ceci : « Ils n'eurent point de règles sacrées pour leurs consciences : l'homme fut bon par force de volonté , d'intelligence , et non par soumission et par crainte . Leurs croyances furent des fables , spirituelles et gracieuses , aimables , » https://books.google.fr/books?id=KTlcAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA72&dq=%22par+force+de+volont%C3%A9%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj04I7flfHuAhUE4BoKHY63DhYQ6AEwAHoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=%22par%20force%20de%20volont%C3%A9%22&f=false

Comment: Ok, ça se tient.

Answer (score 6):

> Il était musculeux, le voilà adipeux.

Comment: MDR, c'est en effet très joli.

Comment: La gonflette à fait ‘pschitt’ … reste la gélatine